# How can I set a listener from another class?

Tags: java, android, listener

```
public class ClassOne implements MessageReceivedListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(Message m) {
        // TODO etc
    }

}
```

Inside `ClassOne` I can say `foo.setOnMessageReceivedListener(this);`

If I had another class called `ClassTwo`, how can I set its listener to `ClassOne`'s listener?

eg...

```
public class ClassTwo implements MessageReceivedListener {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        setOnMessageReceivedListener(???);
    }

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(Message m) {
            // TODO etc
        }

}
```

EDIT: This is for an android applications, these two classes are activities, not standard java classes

Comment: ClassOne and ClassTwo should be having a function setOnMessageReceivedListener. Normally this is not required call backs are used when you wanted to listen for an operation performed by another class.

Comment: you need an instance from classOne in class two. eg `ClassOne one = new ClassOne(); setOnMessageRecievedListener(one);`

Comment: @A.S. The problem with that is that this is an android application. I don't create an instance of the class. I just start it as an activity..

Comment: Are these two classes fragments or Activities?

Comment: @A.S. They are activities

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Only one `Activity` will be running at a time. Change your app's design to Fragments if that helps, or reconsider your concept otherwise.

Comment: @Clay - If you do like to follow Fragments then here is an example. http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassTwo extends Activity implements MessageReceivedListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ClassOne myMessageListener = new ClassOne();
        myMessageListener.setOnMessageReceivedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(Message m) {
        // TODO etc
    }

}
```

I think thats what you want

Comment: 1. @Clay seems to be referring to `Activities`. 2. You will get a NullPointerException in your code.